# Conditional on click function for table rows

Tags: jquery, onclick, conditional-statements

I need table rows to have an onclick function if an anchor tag's text (outside the table) has a specific value. the tr onclick isn't working with the condition set. How can I achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var enabled = ($('a#action-toggle').text() == 'Enabled');
    $('tr[id^=mytablerow-]').each(function(){
        if (enabled) {            
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                alert('action enabled'); 
            });
        }
    });
    $('a#action-toggle').on('click', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        if($(this).text() == 'Disabled') $(this).text('Enabled');
        else if($(this).text() == 'Enabled') $(this).text('Disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: How many #action-toggle do you have on a page?

Comment: I have only 1 #action-toggle on the page.

Comment: Don't cache the enabled, check each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cache, if you cache it then it will be the same value all of the time so once you change the text. Your onclick will still think it's the same since you cached the value

```
$('tr[id^=mytablerow-]').on('click', function(){
   if ( $('a#action-toggle').text() == 'Enabled' ) {
       alert('action enabled'); 
   }
});
```

I think you don't even need the each. Binding it to the selector will already ensure the binding to each of the selectors.

Comment: This won't work, if I later toggle the text to disable, then it will still alert "action enabled".

Comment: Yeah you have to put the conditional inside the onclick function, rather than outside. But the cache issue was my main problem.

Comment: my mistake, I didn't look at the other structure of the code, I updated it

Comment: Well, I'm only showing a small snippet of the code. The each function is necessary for all the other stuff.

Comment: I removed the each, I don't think it is needed. Of course do your testing

Comment: @Thom ok then leave it in. Change what you need to in the real code

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the toggle text every time because it is dynamic.

```
$('tr[id^=mytablerow-]').each(function(){          
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            if ( $('a#action-toggle').text() == 'Enabled' ) {
                 alert('action enabled'); 
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain why you believe the each is necessary? the jQuery().click will handle a large amount of click handlers. However, if you have too many trs, all those click events will slow down your page. Try event delegation using jQuery on with a selector.

I also gave an example of using a class "click-enabled" instead of doing string matching

```
$(function(){
// Instantiate class for enabled / disabled state.
if($('#action-toggle').text() == 'Enabled')
    $('#action-toggle').addClass('click-enabled');
else
    $('#action-toggle').removeClass('click-enabled');

// Update state class and text when clicked
$('#action-toggle').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if($(this).is('.click-enabled'))
        $(this).text('Disabled').removeClass('click-enabled');
    else 
        $(this).text('Enabled').addClass('click-enabled');
    });

// Listen for click events on any trs with id ^= mytablerow-.
// This is 1 event handler that will handle any click on any of those trs, and var self will contain the reference to that specific tr.
$('table').on('click', 'tr[id^=mytablerow-]', function(ev){
    var self = $(ev.target);
    if($('a#action-toggle').is('.click-enabled') ){
        alert('action enabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Example to show how to run multiple actions based on the exact target element. See also:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr[id^=mytablerow-]', function(ev){
    var self = $(ev.target); // $(this) also works
    var td = self.closest('td');
    var tr = td.parent();
    if($('a#action-toggle').is('.click-enabled') ){

        if(td.is('.action1'))
            alert(' Running action 1');

        if(tr.is('.row3'))
            alert('running action row3');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll take some good stuff from this. The each is necessary because I'm performing various operations on multiple elements within each tr, including ajax/php call and response, to rename files and replace the table cells with new names on success, and they are all identified by randomly generated id attributes, the suffix of which is provided by the tr's id. What you see in the op is a very simplified version. I'm doing multiple different ajax functions based on different clicks within different cells in each row.

Comment: It is possible. see the var self = $(ev.target) ? that will tell you exactly which tr / td / inner element the event actually happened, and you can make your logic based on that. I often do that self line, then: var tr = self.closest('tr'); ....